# How to automatically set a foreignkey that cannot be edit for users django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I would like an advice. I am creating a django application where users can register comments, what I want to do is that when a user registers a comment, the user is automatically registered as its author because it does not make sense that a user can register a comment in the name of another user, In order to do this, I have defined my model and views like this

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm, widgets

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class my_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'author': widgets.Select(attrs={'disabled': True}),}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .models import Comment, my_form


def my_view(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = my_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        request.POST._mutable = True 
        form.data['author'] = user # As the form field is disabled the view has to complete it
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponee("Success")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Fail")
    else:
        form = my_form(initial={'author':user})
        return render(request, "my_app/my_template.html", {"form":form})
```

my_template.html

```
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/new_comment/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class=" form-group col-md-4">
                    {{form.author|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class=" form-group col-md-4">
                    {{form.description|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Submit</button>                                                                              
        </form>
        <br>
    </section>
</div>
```

So as the form´s field 'author' is disabled the view have to complete that field but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this maybe there is an elegant with html or with a django class-based view

Comment: One thing in your form is that `fields = '__all__'` is a valid thing to do. But it is not recommended. You would want to specify fields one by one. That is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

If a user cannot add a comment in the name of another user, the common way to do this is not to put author field in the form. In your view, when the form is submitted, you can bind the `request.user` to that comment so that the comment has a user and it is the current user. In you view you have access to `request.user.is_authenticated` boolean. If the user is authenticated, this returns `True`.
Also check out this [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. You might want the user to be logged in to be able to post a comment.
If you are sure the user is authenticated, `form.author = request.user` is the way to go.
If the user cannot post a comment without being logged in, then I suggest you don't display the comment form when you check `request.user.is_authenticated` in your template. Hope this gives you some idea where to go.